# Using field from DE in SMS message

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, mobileconnect, content-builder, sms

I have a question.
I have two options of SMS message creating

1. Use AMPscript like in email building

```
%%[
var @fname
set @fname = [First_Name__c]
%%]
%%=v(@fname)=%%
```

2. 

```
%%[
var @row, @rows, @fname
set @rows = LookupOrderedRows("SMS",1,"StartDateTime desc", "Phone__c", MOBILE_NUMBER)
set @row = row(@rows,1)
set @fname = field(@row,"First_Name__c")
%%]
%%=v(@fname)=%%
```

Why for the first option SMS didn't come but for the second it came? Journey settings for both variants were equal.
Or why we cant use 1st option for sms message?

Comment: Please update your question to include some details about your journey entry event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `First_Name__c` must be in your send context for the personalization string to be valid.  You can use [AttributeValue](https://ampscript.guide/attributevalue) to validate existence of the contextual string.  This'll illustrate the function by returning `Friend` if `First_Name__c` cannot be found.

```ampscript
%%[

set @fname = AttributeValue("First_Name__c")
set @fname = iif(empty(@fname), "Friend", @fname)

]%%
%%=v(@fname)=%%
```

In the second one, `MOBILE_NUMBER` is a [system string](https://ampscript.guide/system-strings) that's present in the send context.  It's available since it's bound in Contact Builder.  I'd update your code to have a fallback value as well:

```ampscript
%%[

set @rows = LookupOrderedRows("SMS",1,"StartDateTime desc", "Phone__c", MOBILE_NUMBER)

if rowcount(@rows) > 0 then
  set @row = row(@rows,1)
  set @fname = field(@row,"First_Name__c")
else
  set @fname = "Friend"
endif

]%%
%%=v(@fname)=%%
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer!

Comment: About journey entry event - it is "Salesforce Data"